# Selecting value in select with special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have the following options in my dropdown:

```
<option value="3:8">N07</option>
<option value="4:7">N08</option>
```

I want to select an option that would match part of the string. For example, I want to match `:8`. I am able to match the first option if I do it without including the colon. In this case `roomID` is 8:

```
var roomOption = roomOptions.filter($(":contains('" + roomID + "')")).first();
```

But I need to include the colon as well. So this doesn't work:

```
var roomOption = roomOptions.filter($(":contains('\:" + roomID + "')")).first();
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match elements based on their `value` attribute, use the [Attribute Ends With Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/):

```
$('[value$=":8"]')
```